# When to remove Timer event handler in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have a WindowsForm application - "Bouncing Balls", so I have a timer for the form
because in each tick I move the balls.

In my form c'tor I have this code:

```
public Form1(){

  timer = new Timer();
  timerHandler = new EventHandler(timerTick);
  timer.Tick += timerHandler;
  timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

now when the user close this application, should I need to remove the 'EventHandler'?
I have an Exit button, so when the user clicks on it, I show him a pop up dialog that ask
him if he really want to quit from the application. if he clicks 'Yes' , i'm closing the application, else nothing happens.

so in my Exit Button code I wrote this code:

```
DialogResult result= MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit",  
                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             timer.Tick -= timerHandler;
             this.close();
        }
```

Should I be worried about the timerHandler or the GC destroyed him when the application closed?

Comment: When user click the application, all objects are destroyed(expect background threads), and no need to worry about that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> now when the user close this application, should I need to remove the 'EventHandler'?

No, there's no need. Apart from anything else, if the whole application is stopping, that means the process will die anyway, so it's irrelevant.

But even if that *weren't* the case, the timer will be eligible for garbage collection at the same time as the form anyway - so this *isn't* a case where the event handler will keep an object alive longer than it needs to be. (That's assuming your `timer` variable is an instance variable, of course.)

EDIT: The above is just addressing the garbage collection side of things. Thinking about it further, it's *potentially* possible (I'm not sure of the implementation details) that there's a race condition here: if the timer ticks after the form has been closed and implicitly disposed, but before the event loop stops running, you could end up with a timer tick which tries to move the balls on a disposed form, which would fail.

The best way of addressing this isn't to remove the tick handler (IMO) - it's to dispose of the timer when the form is disposed (i.e. in the `Dispose` method - possibly by adding it to the container of components, but I'm not entirely sure on that front).

This isn't a matter of whether things will be garbage collected - it's whether the event handler will be called when it's no longer appropriate (because the form has been disposed). If the form closing *immediately* shuts down the event loop, it's fine - but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: thank u for the answer, so can i remove the code line "timer.Tick -= timerHandler" from my code ?

Comment: @Elior: Yes, there's no need for it - at least in terms of garbage collection. Thinking about it further, I *wonder* if there's a race condition here - I'll edit more details into my answer.

Comment: @John Skeet, thank you :) , i'll accept your answer, i'm just waiting that this option will be possible to me, because i just signed up..

Comment: so what you're saying is to dispose the timer when the user want to close the application? but if it's an instance of timer..
(and it is) the garbage collection should handle it himself, no?

Comment: @Elior: See my edit - the garbage collector *will* collect it, but what happens if the timer fires before it's garbage collected?